# Is there a specific synth name/DAW plugin for a sort of 70s jazz flute chorus?

Tags: jazz, synthesizer, daw, flute, vst

There's a sound I hear in some modern alternative music that has such emotive nostalgic properties. It sounds like a flute chorus I've heard in 70s [Japanese Jazz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1sr12EiNgFs) and elsewhere. This short comedic musical [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=56Krr6EwuOQ) prominently features the old-timey flute chorus in the first half of the instrumental. I would love to use this in my music, but my searches for a flute sound from around that time keep giving me the [Korg M1 Pan Flute](https://youtu.be/qoiPkHyEMGI?t=232) which is definitely not what I want. Is anyone aware of a name of a synth effect I can look up, or a plugin/vst that can reproduce this?

Answer (score 1):

That comedy video seems to sample Tina Turner's "What's Love Got To Do With It", which was recorded on a Yamaha DX7 keyboard. Thus, your best chance is getting a DX7 emulation, e. g. Dexed (free) or the one from Arturia, and trying to find the original preset (factory preset #24).

Comment: This led me down a very interesting rabbit hole. Many thanks for introducing me to Dexed, which I will certainly be using in the future. While the video does sample "What's Love Got To Do With It", the trilling flutes are laid _over_ it, and do not come from Tina's song. My search continues. But your research was amazingly thorough and specific, thanks!